# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found, laravel relationship error?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

in my app I have Product and ProductCategory models, a ProductCategory has many Products and a Product belongs to one ProductCategory, in my seed file I succesfully created categories and their products.

Now the issue is in my controller I'm trying to use eager loading method with to load all product categories along with their respective products, like this:

```
$productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products')->get();
```

However I'm getting the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.product_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`product_category_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

These are my models:

Product:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Product extends Model
{


    protected $table = 'products';


    public function productcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'productcategory_id');
    }
}
```

ProductCategory:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class ProductCategory extends Model
{


    protected $table = 'productcategories';


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Models\Product');
    }


}
```

And now my migrations:

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;


class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{


    public function up()
    {


        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('productcategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('productcategory_id')->references('id')->on('productcategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }


    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }


}
```

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;


class CreateProductCategoriesTable extends Migration
{


    public function up()
    {


        Schema::create('productcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }


    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
        Schema::dropIfExists('productcategories');
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }


}
```

Comment: You typed `productcategory_id` and `product_category_id`

Answer (score 0):

*** Here  Category HasMany  Products where Foreign Key Is  productcategory_id.

class Category extends Model 
{ 
        public function products(){ 
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'productcategory_id'); 
    } 
} 

***** Every Product belongsTo A Category..** 
class Product extends Model  
{ 
        public function category(){ 
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class); 
    } 
}

Think Like this.